# How to filter data dynamically on radzen data grid based on Query.Filter?

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, dynamic-linq, asp.net-core-7.0, radzen

I work on blazor server side .asp.net core 7 . I face issue I can't return data after filter from list on Radzen data grid

First I create radzen data grid on razor page

```
 <RadzenDataGrid @ref="myDataGrid"  AllowColumnPicking="true" FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple" AllowFiltering="true" PageSizeOptions="@PagingOptions" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" 
                                                data="@databaseData"
```

second I create list that receive data after filter

```
private IEnumerable<CopyExcelDatabaseClass> databaseData = Array.Empty<CopyExcelDatabaseClass>();

    public class CopyExcelDatabaseClass
    {
     
        public string databaseName { get; set; }
        public int ServerID { get; set; }
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
        public string Severity { get; set; }


    }
```

third function is filter list based on dynamic condition get it from `myDataGrid.Query.Filter`

```
public void getListDataAfterFilter()
{
 var query = myDataGrid.Query.Filter;
 var filteredList = databaseData.Where(query).ToList();
```

this statement return condition Filter from `radzen data grid` after write filters

```
var query = myDataGrid.Query.Filter;
```

return below filter condition

```
(databaseName == null ? "" : databaseName).ToLower().Contains("Menna".ToLower()) and (serverity == null ? "" : serverity).ToLower().Contains("Mon".ToLower())
```

**Updated Post**

I try to get result from above and it worked fine

```
var filteredList = databaseData.Where(item => item.databaseName.Contains("DB_U")).ToList();
```

but issue it static and I need it dynamically meaning based on condition filter `Query.Filter`